# Different Order Id of product from google play

Tags: android, in-app-billing, product, android-pay

I have an app with products, all ships I save in my cloud, today I checked the log and saw two differents order id, and in wallet/merchant not have that order yet.

So my question is: 
Is rigth the order Id?
How long time usually delay to show order in wallet?

Default order ids I got: (2015/03/11)

```
GPA.1355-6245-00X8-05X6X
GPA.1375-4305-10X8-X3807
GPA.1367-7671-943X-3X336
```

Today I got thats: (2015/07/11) Today

```
4496482184183757633.6602695480X6175X
1206201909101041727.52364XX181X38496
```

Any one know?

Obs: The "X" in orders is only to hidden the real number

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem

Comment: the second one those are numbers looks like ios order ids from app store

Comment: Did you get any answer for this ? We are also facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

Google recently changed [orderid format](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-refunds). I am not sure if you're testing in sandbox mode or production. For sandbox mode, order ids might not be correct, and even for production mode, there might be a bug.

For [test mode](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#testing-purchases), Google recommends to use purchaseToken

> You can use the purchaseToken field to identify test purchases.

I think for production too you should use purchase token instead of orderId to identify purchases till we have a better support for new order ids.

**EDIT**

You can use [Purchases.subscriptions: get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get) API in the backend to check if purchase is valid.

> Checks whether a user's subscription purchase is valid and returns its
>   expiry time

All [Purchases.subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions) API methods (get, cancel etc.) require a purchase token instead of order id so you don't need to store order id.

Comment: My app is in production. How can I valid in my backend before send the product? Cause, a user cant get the token? If they was able to get a aleatory order id.